# Selectize js Removes Class Value

Tags: javascript, html, selectize.js

If I add a class to my option, once I use Selectize it will be removed.

For e.g

HTML

```
<select>
  <option value="" class="test"></option>
</select>
```

Js

```
$('select').selectize({
    sortField: 'text'
})
```

This will remove my original class (test) and replaced with selectize classes only. Any clue who to keep it?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `copyClassesToDropdown` to `true`
For reference, please refer to this [link](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md)

```
$('select').selectize({
    sortField: 'text',
    copyClassesToDropdown: true
})
```

Snippet for your reference below.

```css
.pokemon{
     color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/7.3/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/js/selectize.js"></script>
<script src="https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://platform.twitter.com/js/button.93a0c25c2d2f3081c705c98c2d9dec0e.js"></script>

<div class="demo">
    <h2>&lt;select&gt;</h2>
    <div class="control-group">
     <label for="select-beast">Beast:</label>
     <select id="select-beast" class="demo-default" placeholder="Select a person...">
      <option value="" class="pokemon">Select a person...</option>
      <option value="4">Thomas Edison</option>
      <option value="1" class="pokemon">Nikola</option>
      <option value="3" class="pokemon">Nikola Tesla</option>
      <option value="5" class="pokemon">Arnold Schwarzenegger</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <script>
    $('#select-beast').selectize({
     create: true,
     copyClassesToDropdown: true
     sortField: {
      field: 'text',
      direction: 'asc'
     },
     dropdownParent: 'body'
    });
    </script>
   </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, and the default value for copyClassesToDropdown is true.

Comment: Also, I can't find a way to add the **label** attribute to the option as well.

Comment: @itisme_ I thought so too but until/unless you add the `copyClassesToDropdown` ...you can see the snippet doesn't work with the `pokemon` class. That's the main reason behind sharing a snippet because it's not same in documentation